# Golang weird behavior using filepath.Glob

Tags: intellij-idea, go, glob

I'm confused about glob usage on Golang, I'm probably missing some environment variable. I don't know if I'm doing it right.

This code works perfectly fine when ran on my IDE (Intellij IDEA), but when this is ran on the OS via `go run` it doesn't work. I can't figure out what is the difference.

```
package main

import (
    "path/filepath"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {

    file := os.Args[1]

    matches, err := filepath.Glob(file)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("Number of matches:%d", len(matches)))
    fmt.Println(matches)
}
```

Running on OS

```
go run globtest.go /Users/bernardovale/glotest/*.bkp
Number of matches:1
[/Users/bernardovale/glotest/test1.bkp]

ls -l /Users/bernardovale/glotest/*.bkp
-rw-r--r--  1 bernardovale  staff  0 May 27 12:06 /Users/bernardovale/glotest/test1.bkp
-rw-r--r--  1 bernardovale  staff  0 May 27 12:06 /Users/bernardovale/glotest/test2.bkp
-rw-r--r--  1 bernardovale  staff  0 May 27 12:06 /Users/bernardovale/glotest/test3.bkp
```

Running on IntelliJ IDEA

[image: go run on the IDEA]

Comment: You're letting the shell do the glob for you. Print out the args from within your program and see what you're getting.

Comment: you're right, I didn't know that. Thanks a lot. Post it as an answer if you like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference here is that the shell is executing the glob and providing the individual values to your application. When executing from a shell you should wrap a glob in double quotes to make sure it's not evaluated by your shell first.  See the example below.

```
Seans-MBP-2:~ sthorne$ echo Testing*
Testing Testing2 Testing3
Seans-MBP-2:~ sthorne$ echo "Testing*"
Testing*
```